# Ubuntu, Serverless Framework, AWS Credentials Failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, ubuntu-20.04

I cannot seem to get my AWS provider to use my AWS credentials in the Docker Containers

I have ran all of these so far

```
serverless config credentials --provider provider --key key --secret secret
```

&

```
aws configure
```

☝️ *ran through the prompts and plugged in my info*

&

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=blah
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=blah
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=east-whatever
```

But still, get stopped by AWS

```
ServerlessError: AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in our docs here:.
```

I have also generated and regenerated my IAM creds multipule time, also whne I run `aws configure list` it returns

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************67GT shared-credentials-file    
secret_key     ****************6glt shared-credentials-file    
    region                us-east-2      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

I am not sure what else to do, I am on Ubuntu 20.04 using Bash

Comment: as i can there is profile has not been set why dont you try creatigg config snd credential files manually

Answer (score 1):

I will take approach of setting everything using aws-cli ( hence aws cli installation is imp)

- install aws cli
- run `aws configure` -> enter your creds, this info will be stored in profile called `default`  in ~/.aws/credentials file. [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html).
- verify your configuration by checking `~/.aws/config ~/.aws.credentials` file
- for serverless frame work deployment use this `serverless deploy`.
- if mutiple profiles needs to be used use `sls deploy --aws-profile profile-name`